# Best way to store Database Data(many to many relation) in Collection in java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap

My Problem is Here (May be my question title is not proper)

I have Three table

1. **DATA** (which contain foreign key of action and device table )
2. **ACTION**
3. **DEVICE**

one DATA can have multiple actions as well devices.

I have cached DATA table with all rows.
Now **my target is to store** in a way that I can retrieve DATA by particular actionid and deviceid.
Just like query (`select *from data where actionID=123 AND deviceId=456`)

My approach is to take :
to store using `Map<DEVICEID,Map<ACTIONID,DATAs>>` but how to generate this map.
I have three pojo class:

```
public class DATA {
int dataId;
int actionId;
int deviceId;
String dataDetail;
}

public class Action {
int actionId;
int acttionName;
}

public class Device {
int deviceId;
String deviceName;
}

public class GenerateObject {
static List<DEVICE> devices = new ArrayList<DEVICE>();
static List<Action> actions= new ArrayList();
static List<DATA> datas = new ArrayList();
public static void generateCollection(){
    Map<String,Map<String,List>> dataMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String,List>>();
    //Write Code which set dataMap
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance.If any new approach is their than that would be apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you always search by these two attributes, you could create a new class, lets call it `DataIdentifier`, which consists of both actionId and deviceId. To make sure it can be used as a key in a `HashMap<DataIdentifier, List<String>>`:

1. override `public int hashCode()` to return a hash code which is derived from both the `actionId` and the `deviceId` and
2. override `boolean equals(Object other)` to return true when both actionId and deviceId are the same.

You would then use it like this:

```
List<String> dataDetails = datas.find(new DataIdentifier(actionId, deviceId));
```

Comment: thanks for the help but can you please elaborate , how generate HashMap using three list (DATA,DEVICE,ACTION)?

Comment: Do you have everything you need in the DATA table or is there information from the other tables you also need available?

Comment: Currently i only want data objects by actionid and deviceid. First step is how to store that datas in object

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String,Map<String,List>> datas = new HashMap<String, Map<String,List>>();
Map<String,List<T>> actionMap = new HashMap<String, List<T>>;
actionMap.put("actionID", Arrays.asList(1,2)); // assuming T = Integer
datas.put("deviceID", actionMap);
```